# replaygain - normalize each audio file individually

Tags: replaygain

I'd like to normalize multiple .ogg files. Unfortunately replaygain treats multiple files as an album and normalizes according to the loudest file. I'd like to normalize each file to 0dB.

I tried `replaygain -f --no-album *.ogg` without success.

Comment: Replaygain is not normalisation, it's just a volume adjustment on a file/album. Normalisation is making each file peak at a nominal 0dB, a permanent re-encode. Replaygain is a post-process output adjustment & can be tweaked at any time.

Comment: does that mean I cannot get my audio files louder with it? which command-line tool can do it?

Comment: Digital audio has a maximum 0dB peak. Replaygain is just like a volume knob on your hifi, it turns the entire thing up or down, but has a nominal 89dB noise-floor. Basically - you need to know what you actually want before you can ask us how to 'fix' it.

Comment: I'd like to turn the volume knob up, in a way that each file has their max peak at 0 dB

Comment: then you need to normalise, not use replaygain. For that, we'd need to know what software & OS you're using.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, might normalize-audio do the trick?

Comment: I don't know the OS or the tool, sorry. Give it a try.